# Applying "Stack light" concept towards to terminal's background color

Tags: plugins, terminal, colors, background

I like the concept of this "Stack light" as an indicator on whether you're busy or not.  By applying this functions to the terminal, I think it would be cool to see the background color changed, or title's background color.   Only when you have something running your command in a busy mode.

Another idea is having a gif as your background that will be changed due to the nature of the indicators on whether it's busy, idle, or otherwise.

Look in Stack light concept under 'Functions' section >> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_light

Is there such feature, plugins, or existing terminal that does this?

Alternatively, with manual effort, it can be done as follow:
Create `change-background-color.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput setab 4  # Change to blue background
"$@"          # Run any command
tput setab 0  # Restore back to default
```

It conceptually kinda follows but it's too manual when it's not done automatically by terminal's feature.